# Is it possible to write Custom Events so that event handlers are called on LIFO basis?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

I want to create a few custom events, which will always call the registered event handlers in the reverse order of event registration i.e. most recently registered event handler is always called first. Is it possible? These events will be raised by Business Layer classes on certain error conditions, where registered event handlers may be able to overcome the error condition.

Its a purely technical question, whether it is possible to do so or not? Is it possible to override the event chain call order? Does the language (any version of C# 2.0, 3.0, 4.0) support this feature or not?

**EDIT:**

The likely usage will be for error reporting and error recovery where possible. Example, Func A calls Func B which calls Func C. Func C may encounter an error condition and has an event for that. Func A and Func B would have registered for the event, if they are capable of providing an error recovery mechanism. Since Func B is more likely to have the context in which to solve the error, I want to call the most recent registered handler and check event args to see if error is resolved. If yes, I will not even call the other event handlers. If no, I will call the 2nd most recent registered handler, which will be the caller's caller function i.e. Func A.

In most cases, code is usually structured in a way that if Func A calls Func B, then Func B does not call Func A i.e. cyclic calls are usually not there, and order of event handlers will be identical to order of function calls. So if Func A calls Func B which calls Func C, and Func C raises an "error event", the most suitable candidate to handle the error is Func B's event handler, followed by Func A's event handler and so on.

Its like an unwinding of the stack trace and give the most recent caller function the opportunity to consume the event. Any no. of caller functions might be there.

After the event has been consumed successfully by any handler, the Func C which raised the "error event" will proceed. It will check the Event args to determine this. If no handler has consumed the event, Func C will throw exception.

Comment: Can you provide additional detail of your actual business problem? Equivalent functionality can often be achieved by appropriate use of OnEvent() methods stepping up/down the class hierarchy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can iterate the invocation list of the event yourself by using the MulticastDelegate.GetInvocationList() method.  Like this:

```
    public event EventHandler Custom;

    protected virtual void OnCustom(EventArgs e) {
        var handler = Custom;
        if (handler != null) {
            var subscribers = handler.GetInvocationList();
            for (int ix = subscribers.Length - 1; ix >= 0; --ix) {
                var sub = (EventHandler)subscribers[ix];
                sub(this, e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Do beware that this is an iffy solution, you cannot control the order in which other code subscribes the event.

Comment: I just saw you edited your post. In fact, I liked your earlier post more, because it illustrated the step by step process. Can you post the old code again and show the add and remove methods of the event.

Comment: In your current code, it is not clear when will OnCustom get called?

Comment: Nah, it wasn't necessary.  Call OnCustom yourself to raise the event.  This is the standard .NET event raising pattern.

Comment: Ok. 2 questions. Then I need to have an OnEventXXX method for each custom event, which will clutter my business class. Can I not move that code in the Delegate or Event class or elsewhere? Secondly, why do you say "you cannot control the order in which other code subscribes the event." Since I control the order in which event subscribers are called (or I may even choose not to call some subscribers), how does this matter?

Comment: Also, my custom event will have custom parameters instead of EventArgs. If you can repost the custom event's add and remove accessors, it will help me in having finer understanding.

Comment: You can make it look any way you want, I just posted the standard .NET way.  The essential code you need is in the body of OnCustom(), you can move it anywhere you like.  Since you cannot control the order in which code subscribes the event, you also have no well defined order in which you call the event handlers.  Going backwards is just an opposite way of the unpredictable order, it doesn't make it more predictable.  There's a strong hint here that you are trying to solve the wrong problem.